# Doughnut chart but stacked

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have simple bar chart Stacked:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const DATA_COUNT = 7;
const NUMBER_CFG = { count: DATA_COUNT, min: 0, max: 100 };
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  responsive: true,
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Dataset 1",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#cc0000"
      },
      {
        label: "Dataset 2",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: "blue"
      },
      {
        label: "Dataset 3",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: "black"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Can't replicate it to Doughnut by just changing type: "bar" to type: "doughnut"

I need the Doughnut graph to look like the bar one, so I have just 3 groups
It is all looking good on the bar chart, where I have the corect numbers for each colours shown.
In the 2nd graph it's all no organised